# Why is the word 'talentful' not commonly in use anymore and is it incorrect English now?

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence:

> This helping hand should come from the government as companies might ask the talentful  students to appear on  their advertisements in return, which is unethical.

Grammarly Premium warned me that *talentful* is actually not a word.

Ngram says that since 1840s it is not common but peaked in 1845.

There is no result for this word in Cambridge Dictionary online.

Is it incorrect English now? Especially for academic English? If so, why?

Comment: Good research to start, learnerdude.  You might begin to answer your own question (it is  an option).  Please do stick around to [tour] the site and see the [help].

Comment: Just a guess ... 'talented' is easier to say. // Acceptability is eventually governed by idiomaticity (how people actually use the language) and is not totally fixed over time.

Answer (score 1):

[Even in the 1820's, as Ngram Viewer shows,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talentful%2Ctalented&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) "talented" was by far the more popular word. "Talented" appears [in Webster's 1828 dictionary](https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Talented) but "talentful" does not. It appears that the word was never particularly popular; [Wiktionary describes it as archaic](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/talentful) so it would not be considered correct now.

Comment: Yes, but why did it fall out of usage

Comment: We weren't alive in the mid-19th century, so we don't know!

Comment: It fell out of use because "talented" was more popular, and there was no good reason to choose "talentful" over it.